# Google Maps как распарсить координаты и адреса?

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api

Есть такая карта: https://www.google.com/maps/d/embed?mid=zsQ9UGGo4olc.kjZEYRPC8JCk

Нужно вытянуть все адреса и координаты. В коде все координаты есть, но как распарсить не могу понять...

**Обновление**

Если открыть страницу, и посмотреть код, есть переменная Javascript `var _pageData =` и огромная строка с данными. Ниже кусок строки в пример приведено. Вот хотелось бы как-то вытягивать координаты `[49.238966,28.502786]` и адрес `[\"Винница, Магазин «Зброя»\"]`. Строка неоднородна. Свой парсер не осилил написать. Может есть сервисы?

```
,[49.238966,28.502786]\n,[0,0]\n,\"0B12C07F46FA80AB\"]\n,[[\"Винница, Магазин «Зброя»\"]\n]\n]\n,[[\"https://mt.googleapis.com/vt/icon/name\\u003dicons/onion/1494-wht-circle-blank-4x.png\\u0026filter\\u003dff3F5BA9\"]\n,[]\n,1,1,[[,[49.23407050000001,28.4411435]\n]\n,\"MEIxMkMxM0U5RTJDMTIyQg~CiQSHGdlby1tYXBzcHJvLjQ4OWFjYzJlZWVjMzA2NzUYESgAMAASDQBuPkU36PCRUsqgS1g\",\"vdb:\",\"zsQ9UGGo4olc.k9vQOVobjbIM\",[49
```